Adding a co-author in the arXiv version of a conference paper
How can I give credit to a co-worker who contributed significantly to our paper after submission, given that the conference won't allow us to add them as a co-author? The entire team, including the new co-worker, disagrees with the withdrawal option. Our paper has been accepted, and we plan to include their name in the arXiv version. How should I list this on my CV, and how might potential employers/professors view this situation? Will they ignore my CV, assume something unethical has happened, or simply ask and hear my explanation?

What field? The importance of conferences varies

And why would the presence or non-presence of a co-author affect what you put on your CV?

Are the contributions from the co-worker incorporated into the accepted paper or not?

Computer Vision. ECCV 2024. @AzorAhai-him-

Maybe the professor/employer thinks we unethically remove their name and later we decided to change our decision. @AzorAhai-him-

Consider not including the new stuff in the conference paper, and instead publishing an extended journal version of the paper that does include the new stuff (if that's customary in your sub-field of computer science)

They are. They made actual difference. We presented them in the rebuttal and in the came-ready version. @DavidKetcheson

Yea the extended journal version seems reasonable although his contributions did a lot in the rebuttal so we cannot ignore them for the camera-ready version of the conference. So, how do you think about the arXiv version plan and the think professors think when I apply? @lighthousekeeper

@Igy Nobody is going to look at your CV and see a conference presentation without a coauthor, see the same project later and think "they unethically removed their name and then changed their mind," that's really paranoid. People will just assume they contributed later, as they did.

You should add that information to the question: your co-worker's contributions are included in the published paper, even though your co-worker's name is not.

I think you're overthinking this, there are many common circumstances that lead to authorship changes in collaborative work, additions in particular.
The conference rules seem a bit silly, but they are what they are. I'd credit them for their contribution in the presentation and add them to future iterations of the work, as you plan to do, and not worry about it further. You're doing all you can to acknowledge the person who deserves acknowledgement and it doesn't sound like anyone in the situation has a problem with it.
I doubt it will ever be questioned, but if it is you do not need more explanation than the very sensible truth.

Yea but some people on my team are really anxious about a professor who sees this and instantly thinks the worst and neglects their CV for their lab. Do you have any similar experience or have some idea on professors when they look at a CV?

@Igy I have a hard time believing anyone would ever look for this sort of thing in a CV. It's not a useful way to measure ethics in publishing, it's not a useful measure of anything at all. You are overthinking this.

I believe the conference rules are the way they are for two reasons: (1) to prevent people from unethically adding themselves to author lists after acceptance (gift authorship), (2) significant new contributions are not supposed to be added to the paper after the main submission deadline in venues like ECCV since there is no second round of review, so this might also discourage that from happening.

@GoodDeeds There are also practical reasons like "already printed the abstract titles on paper", but I think a more sensible rule would allow for exceptions especially because apparently in this review process significant new contributions were requested by the reviewers (or at least were necessary to respond to them).

Under normal  circumstances, the arXiv verion  of your paper would mention (in the paper itself or in the arXiv's comment field or both) that this paper was presented at conference X. I suggest expanding that to include the information that you've given us here: That the initial submission to the conference was by authors A and B, that the final version included significant contributions by author C, but that the rules of X prevented you from adding C as a coauthor there.

Those new significant contributions suggest that this is now a new and better paper.
If your inablitity to add an author is just your reading of the conference rules, I suggest you ask the organizers for an exception.
In any case. when you present at the conference you should talk about the new version, with due credit to the new author.
You can update the arXiv posting with the new paper and the extra author. In your cv you can list both the conference presentation and the arXiv preprint, noting that it includes later better work.
If appropriate, submit the new version for publication.

We emailed them many many times. They just said you greed upon our rules. It is what it is and you can withdraw if you want. But my concern is what a professor thinks when I apply for their lab.

With both the conference and later arXiv versions on your publication list properly annotated, you're truthful about the history of the work. This should not be a problem

Isn't it just drawing too much attention? I don't know if drawing too much attention a good or bad thing.

Congratulations on doing good work and then making it better. Just let this go.

It's not a new paper -- according to OP's comments above, the contributions in question are included in the conference paper.  So the arxiv and conference papers are the same, content-wise.
